# Update component state using props with another stateless component

Tags: reactjs

I want to update the state of my stateful component 'LoginForm' inside of my stateless component 'InputRetro' I don't know the proper way of achieving it. Please help me.

'LoginForm' component codes:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './LoginForm.css';

import InputRetro from './InputRetro';

class LoginForm extends Component {

    state = {
        loginData : {
            username : null,
            password : null,
        },
        inputs : [
            { id : 'username', label : 'Username', type : 'text' },
            { id : 'password', label : 'Password', type : 'password' },
        ],
    }

    inputsJSX = this.state.inputs.map(input => {
        return (
            <InputRetro id={input.id} label={input.label} type={input.type} key={input.id} />
        );
    });

    handleLogin = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // blank function.
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className='login-form' onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
                { this.inputsJSX }
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

'InputRetro' component codes:

```
import React from 'react';
import './InputRetro.css';

let InputRetro = props => {
    const { id, label, type, placeholder } = props;
    return (
        <div className='InputRetro'>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <input id={id} type={type} placeholder={placeholder} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default InputRetro;
```

I want to update 'LoginForm' component's state values inside of 'InputRetro' component using an onChange or onKeyUp the state values I want to change are state.loginData.username and state.loginData.password when the input tag value of 'InputRetro' component is changed.

more details:

state.loginData.username value will store the value of 'InputRetro' component's input tag with an id of username with an onChange or onKeyUp event. Same in state.loginData.password.

Comment: What you can do is to code your onChange function in your LoginForm class and pass that function in props to the input component

Comment: @SCHYNSAnthony I tried that with this

handleOnChange(e) {
 //this.state.loginData[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
 console.log('Working');
 console.log(e.target.id);
}

it works but when I remove the comment I got an error that state is undefined. and also it will not work with arrow functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a CallBack function from the parent component(LoginForm) to the child component(Input Retro) and then trigger that action in the child component on the button click.

## LoginForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './LoginForm.css';

import InputRetro from './InputRetro';

class LoginForm extends Component {

    state = {
        loginData : {
            username : null,
            password : null,
        },
        inputs : [
            { id : 'username', label : 'Username', type : 'text' },
            { id : 'password', label : 'Password', type : 'password' },
        ],
    }
    
    const ChangeState = (childData, flag) => {
        flag === 1 ? state.loginData.username = childData : state.loginData.password = childData
    }

    inputsJSX = this.state.inputs.map(input => {
        return (
            <InputRetro id={input.id} label={input.label} type={input.type} callBackHandler={ChangeState} key={input.id} />
        );
    });

    handleLogin = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // blank function.
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form className='login-form' onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
                { this.inputsJSX }
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginForm;
```

In the child component you can call the callback function at whatever moment you like.

## InputRetro.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './InputRetro.css';

let InputRetro = props => {
    const { id, label, type, placeholder, callBackHandler } = props;
    const handleClick = (event) => {
        label === 'email' ? callBackHandler(event.target.value, 1) : callBackHandler(event.target.value, 2)
    }
    return (
        <div className='InputRetro'>
            <label>{label}</label>
            <input id={id} type={type} placeholder={placeholder} onChange={event => handleClick(event)} />
        </div>
    );
}

export default InputRetro;
```

Comment: I thought your answer is wrong but I saw the problem on my code. It seems I got an error that callBackHandler is not defined because in LoginForm component I put it below the inputsJSX variable which returns the child component. Thank you for the help.